# What Is the Dying Sun of Thra?

Tags: astronomy, dark-crystal

Here are the "three suns" that the planet Thra orbits in the mythology of *The Dark Crystal*:

[image]

They are all named, according to the Dark Crystal Wiki, the Greater, Rose and Dying suns.  From this picture, we can assume two of the following:

1. The Greater Sun is a G-type main-sequence star, or "yellow dwarf", much like our sun
2. The Rose Sun is a red dwarf

Which leaves us the Dying Sun, which is presumably that purple dot in the middle.  What kind of star could it be?

Comment: Is there any in-universe support for the assumption that the Greater and Rose suns are real types of stars?

Comment: the big yellow one is apparently made of transparent aluminium

Answer (score 2):

Based on the color and size it's probably a brown dwarf, which despite the name are actually theorized to appear [magenta](https://web.archive.org/web/20130508182012/http://astro.berkeley.edu/~gmarcy/astro160/papers/brown_dwarfs_failed_stars.pdf) to the human eye.

Comment: Can you please support your statement with source material. If possible, from the film or the book it's based on or, in your case, from an according physics book.